# Upload UIDocument to iCloud on entering background

Tags: icloud, uidocument

I have an iCloud enabled application that uses UIDocument to manage its data. When the document is open and the application enters background state the document should be saved and uploaded to iCloud. Saving the document when entering background state works fine out of the box, but I'm unable to find a way to make librariand pick up the change. The documents gets only uploaded when the application comes back into the foreground.

I noticed that other iCloud enabled apps - like the iWork app - have this behavior. How can I enabled this in my own app?

I already tried to initiate autosave manually in a beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler block, but this sadly don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple DTS this is due to a bug in the iCloud syncing engine.